# How to Paginate a filtered Collection?

Tags: laravel, pagination

I have a function called `priceFilter()` that filters prodcuts based on the minimum and maximum price of a `product`.

This is the code:

```
public function pirceFilter(Request $request, Produit $produit)
{
    $produit = Produit::query();
    $min = $request->min;
    $max = $request->max;
    $product = DB::table('produits')
        ->select('*')
        ->whereBetween('prix_vent', [$min, $max])
        ->paginate(2)
        ->withQueryString();

    return view('filter-products', compact('product', 'min', 'max'));
}
```

And this is my view code:

```html
<div class="mt-10 hidden sm:flex sm:flex-1 sm:items-center justify-center">
    <div>
        <nav class="isolate inline-flex -space-x-px rounded-md shadow-sm" aria- label="Pagination">
            {{ $product->links('pagination::tailwind') }}
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `links()` function works fine and I get the pages like this below:
[image]

The issue is that when ever I want to show the second page I lose the filter and it shows me an empty page.

Unfortunately I am a bit new to laravel so I haven't tried anything, I am kinda lost here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the DB::table method, utilize Laravel's Eloquent to retrieve the filtered products. This ensures the filter parameters are automatically included in the pagination links.

I don't know why you are injecting the Produit, anyhow I have changed $product to $products.

```
public function priceFilter(Request $request, Produit $produit)
{
    $min = $request->min;
    $max = $request->max;

    $products = Produit::whereBetween('prix_vent', [$min, $max])
        ->paginate(2)
        ->withQueryString();

    return view('filter-products', compact('products', 'min', 'max'));
}
```

And if you don't want to use Eloquent you can easily append the filter parameters to the pagination links.

```
$product->appends(['min' => $min, 'max' => $max]);
```

Comment: works like clockwise thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you look at this laravel
[docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/pagination#appending-query-string-values)

I think you can easily append extra params to paginator links

Comment: how I do that ? based on my code, thanks

Comment: Try $product-> appends(['min' => $min, ‘max’ => $max]);